# Demultiplexing QuickTime MOV files for DirectShow

Tags: directshow, quicktime, directshow.net

I'm working on a small project involving QuickTime media files `(*.mov)` playback. It's a simple output to specialized video card I have in my university lab. The only supported by manufacturer way to work with this video card in Windows OS is to use `DirectShow filters`. But since I have to use QuickTime video files as stream source I encounter the problem with DirectShow. I can't find any way to demultiplex a source file. There is no problem extracting an audio stream from a QT file but I can not find any demultiplexer which can actually split a video stream from it.

So far I tried `Haali Splitter` which were recommended for `*.mov` files by one of my professors but it's unable to correctly split a QuickTime file in to audio and video streams. Is there any other alternatives? Preferably free or open source since while I'm ready to spend a bit on buying QickTime source or slitter filter most of what I found are ridiculously expensive.

I also found the [filter developed by River Past](http://www.riverpast.com/en/prod/quicktime/) which can work as DirectShow filter source. But for some reason while it's working fine with WMP and GraphEdit it refuses to work at all when I'm trying to use it with my program or even in 3rd party graph editing tools. It's just throwing `"UNSPECIFIED ERROR"` which doesn't make any sense. And GraphEditPlus can't even load this particular filter for some reason. So apparently this filter has some kind of mechanism preventing it's usage with anything else but original Micrisoft GraphEdig and WMP.

And is there any kind of description of QickTime MOV file format? I was thinking about trying to write my own demultiplexer but unable to find any complete documentation describing this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the MP4 demux filter at http://gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4. It works with many/most MOV files and is open source.

G

Comment: Unfortunately GDCL Demultiplexor can also split only audio stream. And the thing is I already have a decoder for required video format but it will only accept MEDIATYPE_Video as an input pin. I just need to split video and audio in the source file without decoding it.

Comment: if you email me a link to a short sample, I'll see if I can fix the demux to work with your video type.

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help but I'm already working on it myself. I managed to split audio and video streams. Video stream is a bit shattered but I just started to work on it so think I'll be able to make it work properly.